# Getting a ValueError: Not enough values to unpack for Python dictionary items unpacking

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with a single key-value pair where the key is a string and the value is a set of integers (i.e., `dict[str, set[int]]`).

I want to unpack the key and value by `key, value = some_dict.items()` but am getting a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` error.

I suspected that this was because I wasn't traversing the dictionary properly so I've tried the following which all lead to the same error:

```
>>> key, value = zip(some_dict.items())
>>> key, value = list(zip(some_dict.items()))
```

What works is:

```
for k, v in some_dict.items():
    key, value = k, v
```

How can I unpack the items without using a list?

Comment: You either know the key to access the dict values, or you iterate over it in a for loop.
What is the use case here?

Comment: `key, value = some_dict.items()` is actually an issue because its not returning a key or item, its returning a `dict_items` of the tuple `(key, items)`. `dict_items` is a type of iterable. What `key, value = some_dict.items()` is actually doing is `(key1, items1), (key2, items2) = some_dict.items()`.

Comment: @Ludwig Why is the use case relevant?

Comment: @Shorn Yeah, you're right. I didn't think that through, which explains why asterisk unpacking works as was explained in the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:
If some_dict has multiple keys and values:
With the `zip()` method all keys and values will be unpacked

```py
keys, values = zip(*some_dict.items())
```

`print(keys)` will print an array of keys. `print(*keys, sep="\n")` will print individual key in a newline.

With the `next()` method you can unpack a key and a value at a time.

```py
key, value = next(iter(some_dict.items()))
```